# How do I go about selecting column data in a dataframe for specific row values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

As the question says, I have a data frame which is quite large but looks like:

```
        ID    Count    ValueX    Value 2    Value 3
RowX    1      234.     255.       yes.      yes
RowY    1      123.     135.       543.      342
RowW    1      234.     235.       yes.      yes
RowJ    1      123.     115.       543.      342
RowA    1      234.     285.       yes.      yes
RowR    1      123.     165.       543.      342
RowX    2      234.     255.       yes.      yes
RowY    2      123.     135.       543.      342
RowW    2      234.     235.       yes.      yes
RowJ    2      123.     115.       543.      342
RowA    2      234.     285.       yes.      yes
RowR    2      123.     165.       543.      342
.
.
.
RowX    1233   234.     255.       yes.      yes
RowY    1233   123.     135.       543.      342
RowW    1233   234.     235.       yes.      yes
RowJ    1233   123.     115.       543.      342
RowA    1233   234.     285.       yes.      yes
RowR    1233   123.     165.       543.      342
```

What I want is to be able to select all the values in column `ValueX` where the row is `RowX` for each of the ID numbers 1-1233 and return them in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [30]: df.loc[df.index.isin(['RowX']) & df['ID'].between(1, 1233), 'ValueX'].tolist()
Out[30]: [255.0, 255.0, 255.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.query('1 <= ID <= 1233').loc['RowX', 'ValueX']

RowX    255.0
RowX    255.0
RowX    255.0
Name: ValueX, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would you consider adding `.tolist()` to the expression in your answer since the question asks for a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_df = df[(df.ID.between(1, 1233)) & (df.index == 'RowX')][['ValueX']]

values_list = filtered_df.ValueX.tolist()
```